# FFMPEG - Convert UInt16 Data to .264

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, video-processing

At the moment, I'm trying to convert with `FFMPEG` my raw data in `uint16` format from an infrared camera to `MP4` format or at least to `.h264`.

My current command for ffmpeg is here:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pix_fmt gray16be -s:v 140x110 -r 30 -i binaryMarianData.bin -c:v libx264 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p output.264
```

But my ouput File is not really looking good :(

- [Frame of My Input, its a Nose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PP7c.jpg)
- [Frame of My Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfF5z.jpg)

Here is my Input File: http://fileshare.link/91a43a238e0de75b/binaryMarianData.bin

**Update 1: Little Endian**

Hey guys, would be great if it's possible to get the video output in the little endian byte order.

- [This is a frame shown with ImageJ with the following settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYugG.png)
- [Settings of the shown frame above in ImageJ](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmWXK.png)

Unfortunaley my output doesn't look like this.

- [Output Frame Little Endian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQ5C8.png)

This is my command used to convert the RAW File:

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format gray16le -video_size 110x140 -framerate 30 -i binaryMarianData.bin -vf transpose=clock -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.264
```

Comment: Can you share your input?

Comment: Edited into the hyperlink to the file

Comment: It looks like the data is sideways. How about `-s:v 110x140`?

Comment: Yeah indeed Hermann, the output format of Matlab is a bit confusing

Comment: `.264` is a H264-coded bitstream. LE/BE doesn't come into it. Does ImageJ have a H264 plugin? If it does, *its* decoder will control the byte order of the decoded stream. In any case, the command is encoding a 8-bit planar bitstream, so even the decoder output won't be affected by endianness.

Comment: but is there no difference in the parameters be and le cause it defines the input pixel format of the raw data, or could i define this in converting the h264 container to mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sideways, so the stride has to be corrected and the image rotated.

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -pixel_format gray16be -video_size 110x140 -framerate 30 -i binaryMarianData.bin -vf transpose=clock -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.264
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, man! Im happy this finally works, frankly speaking ffmpeg is a mess with documentation.

Comment: I knew the video input was not correct positioned but i would have never found the correct entry in the documentation to find the right flag to fix this problem, you can't really search it effectively